# Android issue "Program type already present: org.powermock.api.mockito.expectation.WithExpectedArguments"

Tags: java, android, java-8, android-studio-3.0

```
Android issue "Program type already present: org.powermock.api.mockito.expectation.WithExpectedArguments"

The issue appears when I tried to use the mockito in android test
androidTestImplementation ("org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:1.7.4")

The full stack trace

org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task 
':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebugAndroidTest'.
at
```

org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:103)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:88)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
        at `enter code here`org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:623)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:578)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: C:\Projects\vehicle-profiles\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\2.jar, C:\Projects\vehicle-profiles\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\3.jar, C:\Projects\vehicle-profiles\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\4.jar, C:\Projects\vehicle-profiles\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\5.jar, C:\Projects\vehicle-profiles\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\6.jar, C:\Projects\vehicle-profiles\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\7.jar, C:\Projects\vehicle-profiles\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\8.jar, C:\Projects\vehicle-profiles\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\9.jar, C:\Projects\vehicle-profiles\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\10.jar, C:\Projects\vehicle-profiles\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\11.jar, C:\Projects\vehicle-profiles\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\12.jar, C:\Projects\vehicle-profiles\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\13.jar, C:\Projects\vehicle-profiles\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\14.jar, C:\Projects\vehicle-profiles\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\15.jar, C:\Projects\vehicle-profiles\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\16.jar, C:\Projects\vehicle-profiles\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\17.jar, C:\Projects\vehicle-profiles\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\18.jar, C:\Projects\vehicle-profiles\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\19.jar, C:\Projects\vehicle-profiles\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\20.jar, C:\Projects\vehicle-profiles\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\21.jar, C:\Projects\vehicle-profiles\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\22.jar, C:\Projects\vehicle-profiles\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\23.jar, C:\Projects\vehicle-profiles\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\24.jar, C:\Projects\vehicle-profiles\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\25.jar, C:\Projects\vehicle-profiles\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\26.jar, C:\Projects\vehicle-profiles\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\27.jar
        at com.android.builder.profile.Recorder$Block.handleException(Recorder.java:55)
        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:104)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:212)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:124)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:113)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
        ... 33 more
    Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: C:\Projects\vehicle-profiles\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\2.jar, C:\Projects\vehicle-profiles\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\3.jar, C:\Projects\vehicle-profiles\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\4.jar, C:\Projects\vehicle-profiles\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\5.jar, C:\Projects\vehicle-profiles\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\6.jar, C:\Projects\vehicle-profiles\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\7.jar, C:\Projects\vehicle-profiles\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\8.jar, C:\Projects\vehicle-profiles\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\9.jar, C:\Projects\vehicle-profiles\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\10.jar, C:\Projects\vehicle-profiles\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\11.jar, C:\Projects\vehicle-profiles\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\12.jar, C:\Projects\vehicle-profiles\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\13.jar, C:\Projects\vehicle-profiles\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\14.jar, C:\Projects\vehicle-profiles\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\15.jar, C:\Projects\vehicle-profiles\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\16.jar, C:\Projects\vehicle-profiles\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\17.jar, C:\Projects\vehicle-profiles\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\18.jar, C:\Projects\vehicle-profiles\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\19.jar, C:\Projects\vehicle-profiles\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\20.jar, C:\Projects\vehicle-profiles\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\21.jar, C:\Projects\vehicle-profiles\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\22.jar, C:\Projects\vehicle-profiles\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\23.jar, C:\Projects\vehicle-profiles\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\24.jar, C:\Projects\vehicle-profiles\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\25.jar, C:\Projects\vehicle-profiles\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\26.jar, C:\Projects\vehicle-profiles\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\27.jar
        at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:124)
        at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:109)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransformCallable.call(DexMergerTransformCallable.java:101)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ExternalLibsMergerTransform.transform(ExternalLibsMergerTransform.kt:123)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:221)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:217)
        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
        ... 49 more
    Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:76)
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withD8CompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:45)
        at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(D8.java:88)
        at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:107)
        ... 54 more
    Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.failIfPendingErrors(Reporter.java:77)
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.fatalError(Reporter.java:58)
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:67)
        ... 57 more